# replace text with a textbox input using variable

Tags: powershell, replace, textbox

In my script I have a textbox- the user inserts text in it and than I want to change the text in a file (which the script creates earlier) to what the user inserted in the textbox.

**The problem**: it does deletes the part I wanted to be changed in the file- but it doesn`t write the text of the user instead. I also tried to locate the variable in the if loop- and it did changed the text like i wanted, but when I run the script again it wrote the old text in the disabled textbox.

my script is kinda long so I wont post all of it, but here are the importent parts. Thanks for the help!

```
#This creates a checkbox called dsp.z
$objDspCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objDspCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,40) 
$objDspCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$objDspCheckbox.Text = "dsp.z"
$objDspCheckbox.TabIndex = 0
$objForm.Controls.Add($objDspCheckbox)

#This creates the TextBox1 and put it on disable
$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,40) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,150)
$objTextBox1.TabIndex = 3 
$objTextBox1.text = $text1
$objTextBox1.Enabled = $false
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)

#This creates a checkbox for textbox1
$objDsp2Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objDsp2Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(430,40) 
$objDsp2Checkbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$objDsp2Checkbox.TabIndex = 0
$objForm.Controls.Add($objDsp2Checkbox)

#Enables the textbox when user check the box:
#textbox1
$objDsp2Checkbox_OnClick = {
if ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $true)
{
    $objTextBox1.Enabled = $true  
}
elseif ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $false)
{
    $objTextBox1.Enabled = $false
}   
}
$objDsp2Checkbox.Add_Click($objDsp2Checkbox_OnClick)

#variables
$text1=$objTextBox1.Text

#This creates the ok and cancle buttons:
#ok Button 
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,155)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click(
{
 if (($objDspCheckbox.Checked -eq $true) -and ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $true))
 {
    New-Item $path -itemtype file -name Dsp.json -value "old" ;((Get-Content "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") -replace 'old', $text1 | out-file "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") ;$objForm.close()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Change This Line (specifly the `$text1`) to `$objTextBox1.Text` :

```
New-Item $path -itemtype file -name Dsp.json -value "old" ;
((Get-Content "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") -replace 'old', $text1 | 
Out-file "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") ;$objForm.close()
```

To:

```
New-Item $path -itemtype file -name Dsp.json -value "old" ;
((Get-Content "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") -replace 'old', $objTextBox1.Text | 
Out-file "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json") ;$objForm.close()
```

I'm not sure if it's the case but if you just need to save the textbox text to file there's an easier approach :

```
$objTextBox1.Text | Out-file "c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json\dsp.json")
```

Comment: Great! thats what i wanted, i have a built file with parameters and i wanted them to be changed to what the user writes. thank you!

Comment: but do you know why it didnt work the way i tried it? because i defined $text1=$textbox1.text so it should be the same no?

Comment: `$text1=$textbox1.text` is a one-time operation that copies the value of `$textbox.text` to the variable - it doesn't link them.